# health risks for late sleeping?

Tags: sleep

I have the bad habit of late sleeping since I sleep between 1-4:30 AM every day
It's very rare for me to sleep `earlier` before this time
So my question is what are the health risks of late sleeping?
Are there any scientific Experiments,peer-reviewed papers regarding this subject?

Comment: I hope that I do not -Duplicating things- here This question is close -somehow- for my question 
http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/1415/can-long-term-sleeping-at-day-damage-your-health

Comment: It’s a good question, but I do think it's a duplicate. If some aspect of this is not addressed in the other question, please [edit] yours to focus on that and flag so we can see about re-opening. Thanks!